# sharepoint revoke data connections from an excel workbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint

i made a huge mistake and sent a colleague an excel that i exported from sharepoint.

The excel has a data connection to all my sharepoint data, is there a way to severe data connections form sharepoint so that he wont be able to see my sharpoint data?

or what other options or recommendations would you give me?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is prevent your colleague from getting more data, but there's nothing you can do to strip of them of the data they now have (since connections are not dynamic). To keep them from getting more, you'll need move the list, which will force a new address on the list and "sever" the link to that spreadsheet. The best way to go about that is saving the list as a template with content, redeploying it with a different name (and address), and deleting the list in question.